# Creating a slider function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a carousel (i know there are plugins out there but i want to create my own). i am struggling to get this bit of code to be placed inside a function as i have to return a true or false value for the code to run again. so far i have this code that is repeated:

```
if(!active) {
        active = true;
        $('#box ul').animate({ 'left': left_indent }, 500, function () {
            $('#box li:last').after($('#box li:first'));
            $('#box ul').css({ 'left': left_value });
            active = false;
        });
    }
```

i have trid placing it into a function like so:

```
function slider(left_indent, left_value) {
$('#box ul').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 500,function(){   

    $('#box li:first').before($('#box li:last'));          
    $('#box ul').css({'left' : left_value});

    var active = false;
});
```

}

and i have tried calling it like this:

```
if(!active) {
        active = true;
        slider(left_indent, left_value);
    }
```

every time i call that function i cant seem to get active to return false. I am not sure what i am missing.

this is all my code so far:

```
$(function () {
var item_width = $("#box li img").outerWidth();
var left_value = item_width * (-1);

$('#box li:first').before($('#box li:last'));
$('#box ul').css({ 'left': left_value });

var active = false;
$("#next").click(function () {
    var left_indent = parseInt($('#box ul').css('left')) - item_width;

    if(!active) {
        active = true;
        $('#box ul').animate({ 'left': left_indent }, 500, function () {
            $('#box li:last').after($('#box li:first'));
            $('#box ul').css({ 'left': left_value });
            active = false;
        });
    }
    return false;
});

$("#back").click(function () {
    var left_indent = parseInt($('#box ul').css('left')) + item_width;

    if(!active) {
        active = true;
        slider(left_indent, left_value);
    }
    return false;
});
```

});

function slider(left_indent, left_value) {
    $('#box ul').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 500,function(){

```
    $('#box li:first').before($('#box li:last'));          
    $('#box ul').css({'left' : left_value});

    var active = false;
});
```

}

any advice would be great. thanks in advance

Comment: active is a global variable that i declare at the top.. ill edit my question to show you call my code. ill also try and set up a jsfiddle for you to have a look at.

Comment: here is a jsfiddle of my current code http://jsfiddle.net/saunders1989/AvzvJ/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

active was not in the same scope. see working exampe http://jsfiddle.net/AvzvJ/7/

however its bad style to use a semaphore like active for this.

Comment: i can only go back 1 slide. then it stops.

Comment: i can get it to go backwards constantly but if you click back a lot of times it goes a bit wonky. see this for the example - http://jsfiddle.net/saunders1989/AvzvJ/8/

if you click the next button you will see what i would like it to do

Comment: you got it to work. thank you :) now i will go through the code to learn my mistake

Comment: ahh i see where i went wrong. a very silly mistake ony my part

Answer (score 0):

You can't really return functions from a callback like this in a useful way. Since the outer function would return active before the callback altered it. Also you redefined/rescoped active with 'var' so you wouldn't be changing an outer active anyway. What you need is to have active in a shared scope and do the test at the click handler.

Something like:

```
var active = false;

//assumes left_indent, left_value defined further up
$('#slideRightBtn').click(function(){
    if(!active){ slider(left_indent,left_value)); }
});

function slider(left_indent, left_value) {

    //Don't use 'var' for active here
    //that sets a new var 'active' in the scope of this func

    active = true;
    $('#box ul').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 500,function(){   

        $('#box li:first').before($('#box li:last'));          
        $('#box ul').css({'left' : left_value});


        active = false;
    });
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. that was a silly mistake putting that var there. i have placed your code in but im still getting the same issue.

i do this when i call it in the click function 
`code` 
$("#back").click(function () {
        var left_indent = parseInt($('#box ul').css('left')) + item_width;

        if(!active) {
            active = true;
            slider(left_indent, left_value);
        }
        return false;
    });

Comment: Oh, NM. Misunderstood intent of return false

Comment: I would accept your answer but i can only accept 1. you were also correct now looking at the working example thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just drop `var` from the last code line inside your function if you want to modify a variable in the outer scope or a global one, just have:

```
function slider(left_indent, left_value) {
$('#box ul').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 500,function(){   

    $('#box li:first').before($('#box li:last'));          
    $('#box ul').css({'left' : left_value});

    active = false; // Changed!
});
```

Note: ...but PLEASE don't do this. The fact that you can do this - modify a variable in the outer scope, not just access it's value is a "bad thing" about Javascript - in a "sane" language like Python you can't do this for example! Some Javascript "replacements" like [LiveScript](http://gkz.github.com/LiveScript/) even make this impossible (actually you have to use special syntax for it), but unfortunately the more popular CoffeeScript does not :( Pick a good Javascript book and learn to write well structured code if you move on to anything more complex.

Comment: is there a better way youd suggest for me to do this?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with modifying an outer scope value. Especially when you're dealing with callbacks in a language with first-class functions and closures.

Comment: @user720414 my bad, I just now realized that it's the function called when the animation complete. yes indeed, for something like an event-handler or event-handler-like this is the only practical way to do it. sorry for the harsh comment, the `var` at the beginning just popped into my eyes and I didn't "digest" the rest of the code properly :)

Comment: @ErikReppen sorry, my bad, I just answered before taking a better look at the context. Indeed, for an event-handler-like function like this it's the only practical solution. For other cases, I always tend to feel a strong pull towards the "dark side" - functional programming and its purity :)

Comment: @NeuronQ thats okay. i was a bit confused because i always thought that was the better way. i did start off with a class and then i toggled it and placed it on the current li. then i changed my mind and code for the better. thank you for helping though

Comment: Access to outer-scope is pretty much the key to JS's power and flexibility. It's still a crummy idea to rely on global or overly general state vars/objects in complex apps, but in JS understanding the spirit of the rules established in other language paradigms is more useful than attempting to apply them directly. And take Crockford with a grain of salt. The JS community owes him many props but his bad parts and JS Lint rules aren't things we all agree on.